# Response.Redirect going to wrong destination

Tags: c#, .net, response.redirect, network-traffic

I am working on a c# .NET website in which the user can click on a link and get redirected to another web page in a separate website also owned by us.  The code is very easy to understand, there is a switch followed by a call to `Response.Redirect(the_url_we_want_to_go_to)`.

I have debugged it numerous times and I can confirm that when the debugger hits this redirect line that the parameter is correct.  It points to the QA version of this other website.  `qa.samplesite.com` lets say.  However, the browser does not go there.  The browser instead hits the test environment instead. Lets call it `test.samplesite.com`. This is the problem.

I understand there are a million things in between the app servers these two separate websites are on, but maybe one of you has seen something like this before.  More specifically, is there a way to catch outbound traffic in the debugger or is there a way to see outbound traffic on the app server itself (in IIS)?  I am familiar with intercepting inbound traffic inside of httpmodules.  Maybe this isnt a stackoverflow question...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: check the local `host` file on the server/work station the app is hosted on and make sure the request isn't being re-routed...

Comment: You can use wireshark to capture the packets and inspect them. Maybe a URL rewrite setting in IIS...

Comment: nslookup (from the command line) will let you check if a domain name is resolving to the ip that you expect your qa site to be using.

Comment: I would suggest firebug or fiddler on the client side and see what it's getting.  You might be bouncing to QA and being redirected back to test.  But find out what the client is seeing.  That will tell you where to look.

Comment: currently trying some of these suggestions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the very nice HTTP sniffer "Fiddler". It will allow you to see all HTTP requests. You should verfiy that a) the redirect target is correct (it might be overwritten later in the request pipeline. A Response.Redirect is not the final word) and b) that you don't have a second redirect after the first one.

Comment: as suggested I used fiddler and can see that the app is redirecting properly.  There is something on the recieving end sending it to the test environment. THANK YOU FOR YOU HELP

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the overload of Response.Redirect as

Response.Redirect("url_here", true);

This will stop the response on current page (as endResponse is set to true) and redirect to the url.

If you still have the issue, then this might be some name resolution error.

Check to see you your hosts files in the windows directory found here

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

Hope this will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured a similar issue I had. It was quite silly. I had copied some .aspx pages making minor changes. The page where I tried to redirect the client, had it's "CodeBehind" setting wrong. So it redirected to the right page, but loaded the CodeBehind from another page!